# PPC Applications on Lion

Tags: macos, compatibility, powerpc

Is there any way to play PPC applications on Lion without running them in a VM?

The application in question is [Halo Demo.](http://www.macgamefiles.com/item/18748/Halo-Demo/)

Comment: Erm, why did I get a down vote?

Comment: Not sure. I think it's a great (if overoptimistic) question.

Comment: Probably b/c PPC applications can't run in Lion. Just a guess...and no, it wasn't me.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Lol.

Comment: An additional option would be to install Snow Leopard using VMWare (or another Mac). Then install Halo and update it to the latest version (2.0.4), which is a universal binary. From there, you can zip the game (.app) and transfer it somewhere safe. To install it under Lion, just drag it to the /Applications folder. From that point on, you can run it or update it without need of Rosetta.

Comment: You may wish to follow http://www.lionrosetta.com/. It doesn't contain anything useful just yet, but it looks like someone is at least trying to organize a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. And if there was an emulator, it probably wouldn't be fast enough for games (unless it was the equivalent of Rosetta).

Comment: It wouldn't be playable with a Rosetta emulator either. Half speed at best.

Comment: Have you tried it, or are you making an assumption?

Comment: @ChrisPage It sounds like an assumption. The game is from 2005 and requires nothing more than a 800MHz G4/G5, 256MB RAM, and a 32MB AGP Video Card. Modern Macs should have no problem whatsoever playing this game even under virtualization.

Comment: @ChrisPage To provide a comparison, a 2004 Power Mac G5 with a 2.0 GHz core, 512 MB of RAM, and a 64MB NVIDIA GeForce scored a 1700 on GeekBench which could run the game just fine. Most Macs from 2009 up score around 4000: http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/mac-benchmarks/

Comment: @cksum - but PPC code running on Intel is not using virtualization it is using emulation which is much slower

Comment: @Mark There is no way to run PPC code on Lion. Virtualization is currently the only option. So considering that no emulators actually exists that will run PPC on Lion, how can they say it will run at half-speed? Looks pretty clear that it's not based on any actual data.

Comment: @Mark, just a minor note about implementation: Rosetta is a translator, which converts the Intel code to PowerPC, then runs it, rather than interpreting it (which "emulation" may imply). So, it won't be as fast as code generated from source with an optimizing compiler, but it will generally be fairly decent code and perform "well".